# XCode 8 doesn't show images in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode8

After updating xcode all images in the storyboard appeared as question marks (as it doesn't find them). I tried to remove/add them, cleared derived data but still all image views show quesiton marks. If anyone has any idea what might be the problem ?

Comment: Do you see these images in the Project Navigator pane on the left? can you point to one of these and verify its "Full Path" in the right pane of Xcode?

Comment: the fullpath of the images is going to assets catalog where they are

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same problem and I found out that it's because I don't have the image in the size that corresponds to the "View as" device selected in storyboard (bottom left).

If you've selected a device that needs the @2x image (example: iPhone 6s) and you only have the @3x image (as I did) you will see the question mark. If you add the size for the image that corresponds to the device size that you are using for storyboard, the image will appear in your imageView.

**Basically, you want to have the image in all 3 sizes: @1x, @2x and @3x.**

Comment: This was my problem too. I had my images as @3x

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue if you run your project and your image displays in simulator. Sometime is you change `size classes` then also this happens. 
for example if you are using multiple size class like `wA,hA` and `wC,hr` and you set constraints for `any,any` and `compact,regular` both and if you keep `any,any` selected in interfacebulder then it will show images properly but if you change it to `compact,regular` then it will shoe `question mark` because of `simulated metrics's size`. So, if it is not affecting output then it is not an issue!

Comment: Its showing the images correctly on devices/simulator. Actually i didnt play with the new interface builder until now and i see that there is no Any Any or selection of size classes at all. In Xcode 7 i had different layouts for any any and ipad size classes so maybe its the case that you said.

Comment: yeah!!! refer [https://developer.apple.com/xcode/](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/), check images in this link that it hows shows size classes in xcode 8!

Comment: So the normal preview for any device (without in "vary for traits" mode) equals to the previous "any any" as i understand it ? When settings image in this normal mode should be visible in all devices previews right ? But in my case its not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use xcassets catalog for your images:

**1)** Access Assets.xcassets

[image]

**2)** Create new **Image Set** or choose from the list and update existing one

[image]

**3)** Place your image variants in its **@1x, @2x and @3x sizes**:

[image]

Call your image in your code like:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "NewImageName")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I was in the same situation and came to know that xcode 8 storyboard removes frames and that is why images are not showing. Therefore you have to put appropriate constraints on uiimageviews and then you have to force constraints on by writing this code.

```
UIImageView *uiv = [cell viewWithTag:100];
[uiv setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[uiv setNeedsLayout];
[uiv layoutIfNeeded];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 3x images in your Assets that you want to work with and you have already Chosen the Initial Device View to some 2x device, then do the following:

1. Open Storyboard file in Xcode 8.
2. Go to File Inspector -> Interface Builder Document.
3. Opens In -> Select Xcode 7.x
4. Save & Close The Storyboard.
5. Open storyboard again and Choose The Initial Device View To iPhone6s Plus.