# Xcode8 Interface Builder UIImageView's shows unknown image on different devices

Tags: uiimageview, interface-builder, xcode8

recently I've updated my iOS project into Swift 2.3 which is required by Xcode8. There is a new feature in interface builder introduced in Xcode8 which is the `View As:` function where I can switch around to different devices and view the outcome straight from interface builder without actually running the app. This quickly become my favourite function in Xcode8. But I've noticed some buggy behaviour using this function when dealing with UIImageView.

In interface builder, UIImageView display the image correctly only in iPhone 6s Plus after I've enter the image source. It shows a big question mark on the image after I switched to other device in the `View as:` option.

[image]

As you can see, the image display correctly when I set it to View as iPhone 6s Plus.

[image]

When switch to any other devices, the image becomes unknown. Although this won't affect the final outcome, the image still display correctly when app run. Just it feels so wrong where it can't display correctly in the interface builder.

Comment: I'm having this problem too, but still haven't figured out how to work around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just answered the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39571008/xcode-8-doesnt-show-images-in-storyboard).

The Solution:

I had the same problem and I found out that it's because I don't have the image in the size that corresponds to the "View as" device selected in storyboard (bottom left).

If you've selected a device that needs the @2x image (example: iPhone 6s) and you only have the @3x image (as I did) you will see the question mark. If you add the size for the image that corresponds to the device size that you are using for storyboard, the image will appear in your imageView.

**Basically, you want to have the image in all 3 sizes: @1x, @2x and @3x.**

Comment: It works after i putting 2x and 1x images in my image assets. However it just feel doesn't make sense where the image can be display in run time, but can't display in IB when both 2x and 1x images are absence. Anyway, thanks :)